# Unable to resize an image in Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

We have an image in hdf5 file, which we want to extract and drop it into the BookDown pdf

here is the code which is doing that

```
insertImage <- function(hdfFilepath, datasetPath) {
  library(rhdf5)
  library(magick)
  hdfimagedata <- h5read(hdfFilepath, datasetPath)
  image <- image_read(hdfimagedata)
  image <- image_scale(image,"300%")
  plot(image)
}
```

what every I give the scale the image size does no increase and sticks to the size shown below
The image is a very HQ image

We have also tried with option of `image_scale(image,"2000x2000!")` and we also tried `fig.height` and `fig.width` options, but did not yield the expected result. The image size remains the same irrespective of any number assigned to height and width

How to enlarge the image i.e. zoom to fit to page

PN: we don not have any problem with render quaility

[image: sample pdf with image]

Hi, I got it to maxime but now the image overlaps the text

```
  image_resize(image,geometry_size_pixels(width = 300, height = 300))
```

[image: Image overlapping text]

And the Image rendered is Inverted too.

here is the header defined in **index.rmd**

```
--- 
title: "Document"
author: ""
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::pdf_book
documentclass: book
classoption: openany,oneside
link-citations: NO
geometry: margin=2cm
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book."
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: 'Chapter'
---
```

please help

Comment: Can you find a way to isolate the problem to either `magick` or `bookdown`?

Comment: Hi. There seems to be no problem with the magick library as we have rendered a file from the hdf5 and saved it to a location. and the size and the quality remains same. I think its the bookdown

Comment: I've just tested your function for inserting an image from an hdf5 file in a `bookdown` project and it works like a charm. If you think that `bookdown` is the issue, please provide some details (for starters, the YAML header). Providing the hdf5 file could also help.

Comment: Was the inserted image had the same dimensions for height and width? Please make sure to use an image with more height than width..... For me the square image insert perfectly

Comment: It was a 24bit 227x149 image of a rose from [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5image.html). Again, I encourage you to provide some details about your bookdown project.

Comment: @M.A. have added the code. please do let me know if we need more code to debug this

Comment: Looks fine too me. Could you provide the hdf5 file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution to the above problem is

```
insertImage <- function(hdfFilepath, datasetPath) {
  library(rhdf5)
  library(magick)
  hdfimagedata <- h5read(hdfFilepath, datasetPath)
  image <- image_read(hdfimagedata)
  image <- image_scale(image,"300%")
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot(image)
}
```

This helped

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```